# ROS Answers SE migration: hector slam

Tags: hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys, i tried to run the hector_slam with my bagfile .however the rviz doesn't show anything.
instead it come out this at the terminal.i have tried the [SettingUpForYourRobot](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot) tutorial but it does not seem to work at all.

im rather new here,so please help me.thanks :D

```
[ WARN] [1427877911.218559354, 1378884604.791841348]: No transform between frames /map and scanmatcher_frame available after 20.001779 seconds of waiting. This warning only prints once.
[ INFO] [1427877911.716060193, 1378884605.295818198]: lookupTransform base_footprint to /laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
[ INFO] [1427877912.220115826, 1378884605.799589257]: lookupTransform base_footprint to /laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
[ INFO] [1427877912.723062304, 1378884606.302934693]: lookupTransform base_footprint to /laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
[ INFO] [1427877913.227183889, 1378884606.806661066]: lookupTransform base_footprint to /laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
[ INFO] [1427877913.730203378, 1378884607.310326008]: lookupTransform base_footprint to /laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
[ INFO] [1427877914.233894742, 1378884607.813616032]: lookupTransform base_footprint to /laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
[ INFO] [1427877914.737839807, 1378884608.317104749]: lookupTransform base_footprint to /laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206389/hector-slam/) by [HELPME](https://answers.ros.org/users/22030/helpme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably the required transformation are not broadcasted or you mismatch frame names. Run

```
 rosrun tf view_frames
```

to check broadcasted frames and compare result with used Hector slam configuration. If you not solve you problem please post the view_frame result and your Hector slam configuration.

### UPDATE

Sorry, I was not clear: the output from

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

is the generated pdf file that contains the TF tree. You should post this file!

About Hector Slam configuration: the file you posted IS NOT the Hector Slam configuration: you have to post the parameters passed to hector slam node when you run it!

### UPDATE for amsoufari

The LaserScan message contains an header which include the reference frame for scan data. In your bag file the LaserScan messages published with /robot0/laser_0 topic use robot0_laser_0 as frame and you are not broadcasting this frame. Try to change laser_link robot0_laser_0 in last tf in your launch file, it should work!

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2015-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HELPME](https://answers.ros.org/users/22030/helpme/) on 2015-04-01**:
hi, thanks for helping me out. i have edited and post the view_frame result and hector slam configuration

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2021-12-03**:
For 20.04 ros noetic, use:

```
rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py
```